# Query Error : field "Contact Key" required for targeted DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, automationstudio

Good morning,

I have a Synchronized DE [Contacts_Salesforce_9] and I have to write a query to link it to a Regular DE because I need to put it as an entry data source in a Journey.
However, with the Check Syntax, I found this error (image): [image: SQL query error]

So ContactKey is not recognized as a field for the DE.
I solve it writing in select "[_contactkey] as ContactKey", but I don't know why it is correct.

Anyone could help me to understand please?

Answer (score 0):

This is because data extension field names cannot start with an underscore (only system-generated data extensions like this synchronised one can have field names that start with underscores). Does your target data extension have the field `ContactKey`?

As you've noted, using an SQL alias is the correct method for resolving this.

Comment: ContactKey is indeed in the target Data Extension, as per the error message: it is present, and is set to non-nullable, hence you can't have a query updating this data extension and not having the field in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Sales Cloud Contact ID as your Contact Key in SFMC. Hence the correct syntax would be:

```sql
SELECT 
ID AS ContactKey,
Email,
FirstName,
BirthDate
FROM
ENT.Contact_Salesforce_9
```

You also only need square brackets if there are spaces in your field names.

The variables with underscore are [personalisation strings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm), only available in Ampscript (you can't use them in SQL). Also, `_contactkey` does not have it's own personalisation string, but you can resort to `_subscriberkey`, which is essentially the same.

Comment: Thank You Lukas for your answer. I confirm that in the DE, the ContactKey relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key, and yes the ID is the Primary Key.

Comment: Did you try running my query, @AndreaPozzi ?